# Sanitize dollar value before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, currency

I have an input field on a form that has the users enter in a dollar amount. I'm using autoNumeric to mask that field so that as a user inputs 1000, it displays 1,000.00 in the text field.

The column in the database (requested_amount) is a decimal with precision => 8 and scale => 2.

I've made a callback based on other SO answers that attempts to strip the comma out of the input before validating and saving to the database.

```
def strip_commas_from_dollar_fields
  self.requested_amount = self.requested_amount.to_s.gsub(',', '')
end

# Callback
before_validation :strip_commas_from_dollar_fields
```

The params hash that is passed through then I submit the form:

```
 "requested_amount"=>"80,000.00"
```

However, when I view the number in console, it shows:

```
 => 80.0
```

I need the number to be 80000.00 in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because:

```
def strip_commas_from_dollar_fields
  p self.requested_amount // <- here is 80.0 already

  self.requested_amount = self.requested_amount.to_s.gsub(',', '')
end
```

check it. So, instead of this way try to create wrapper around `requested_amount` field:

```
def requested_amount_wrapper=(val)
    self.requested_amount = val.to_s.gsub(',', '')
end

def requested_amount_wrapper
    self.requested_amount
end
```

and use this wrapper field in your hash parameters:

```
"requested_amount_wrapper"=>"80,000.00"
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what you mean by using requested_amount_wrapper in my parameters? I changed the field name in the form to requested_amount_wrapper but was getting unpermitted params error. I then added requested amount wrapper to my controller and am now getting an unknown attribute error on requested_amount_wrapper.

Comment: I mean that need to use `requested_amount_wrapper` field name instead of `requested_amount` in your view (in your form).

Comment: OK I've done that. I am seeing a msg in terminal saying : Unpermitted parameters: requested_amount_wrapper. The params hash is showing  "requested_amount_wrapper"=>"120,000.00" but the value isn't saving to requested_amount. I'm seeing nil in console.

Comment: Try to add `requested_amount_wrapper` parameter instead of `requested_amount` to permit parameters list. Seems like `strong_params` exclude `requested_amount_wrapper` parameter from permit parameters list.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I have about 25 fields that will require this across the site.. this will be a lot of _wrappers! Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to simplify this approach try to create helper which will use [alias_method_chain](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain) to replace model properties to your wrappers.

Comment: I'll need to dig into the method you just mentioned. I don't understand it at first glance but I'll see if I can understand it better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72438/discussion-between-questifer-and-maxd).